# Can I copy an Sprite?

Tags: android, andengine

I was wondering if I can copy a sprite

```
AnimatedSprite X = 
  new AnimatedSprite(200,100, resourceManager.enemyexplode, vbom);
```

How can I copy this so that I can use it whenever I want and not using `scene.attachChild(X)` ? (or I just use it once, just for the main Sprite)

Comment: I think this is java stuff not andengine one. You have to maintain more than one reference for you object.

Answer (score 1):

if you want copy the  sprite then you have to deep copy texture region of that paricular sprite as follows:

```
 AnimatedSprite animateSprite = new AnimatedSprite(200,100, animTextureRegion.deepCopy(), vbo);
```

Comment: and how am I gonna suppose to use the copied sprite? :)

Comment: if you want to perform different tasks on same sprite then you have to use deep Copy.If you don't do this then similar  effect will be shown on both sprites.